# Maven test dependency transitive dependencies override versions of compile transitive dependencies

Tags: maven

Assume project A has **compile** dependency B->C->guava-20.0
Now assume project A has **test** dependency D->guava-31.1

Now in the resulting production jar we will have **guava-31.1**
The question here is that Maven bug or similar? To me it must not be allowed for test   dependency to affect anything in runtime class path at all. But it does - it overrides guava version!

Thanks for any clarification.

Here is the pom example. Spring Eureka client depends on guava version 19.0 and if wiremock dependency is missing - then guava-19.0 goes to production jar.
However, once wiremock dependency (which depends on guava-32.1.3) is added (with test scope!) - guava-32.1.3 goes to production jar instead!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>mavendemo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo1</name>
<description>demo1</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wiremock</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: `test`dependencies can override `compile` dependencies, but they will not go into the production JAR. Instead, I would expect you have no guava at all in the production JAR (which is also bad).

Comment: They override the version of the same compile dependency and this version goes to the production jar and to me this is the defect. Guava is just an example.

Comment: Can you show us the POM? This should not be the case.

Comment: I updated the description with pom sample.